# cordova app crashes on startup in ios 11 beta

Tags: cordova, requirejs, ios11, cordova-ios

I have a cordova app which works fine in xcode 8.3.3. I am trying to test it in iOS 11 using xcode 9.0 beta and it crashes on startup in some assembly code whose last lines are:

```
  0x110d9179b <+91>:  jmp    0x110f4027c               ; symbol stub for: objc_retain
    0x110d917a0 <+96>:  leaq   0x1ba5ad(%rip), %rax      ; "*** CFRetain() called with NULL ***"
    0x110d917a7 <+103>: movq   %rax, 0x3b946a(%rip)      ; gCRAnnotations + 8
->  0x110d917ae <+110>: ud2
```

The crash is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on the last line.

- I tried running the cordova skeleton app and it works fine.
- I replaced my index.html with the one from the skeleton app and it
  didn't crash.
- I put an alert statement in the first line which should
  be called in my app but it doesn't appear, so I guess the app crashes before reaching it.
- I also tried updating requirejs to the lastest version but it didn't help.
- I removed all the plugins from the project and it still crashes, so I guess it's not plugin related.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a problem with xcode 9 beta 3. It was solved when I upgraded to beta 4.